# Finding the capacity of GeoServer to handle load

Tags: geoserver, wfs

I am using GeoServer 2.18.0 war file under Tomcat 9.0, deployed all this into AWS instance m5.xlarge

**Details :**

- GeoServer contains 250+ layers,  includes vector and raster datasets.
- In case of raster data, it is uploaded to GeoServer & vector data is coming from PostgreSQL database.
- In addition, Nginx server is used as reverse proxy server.
- 75 % requests are WFS, 20 % requests are WMS and 5 % requests are WCS
- PostgreSQL DB is tuned.
- WFS Usage : Data download, WMS Usage : Preview data, WCS Usage : Preview data.
- Followed [Production-settings](https://docs.geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/adv_gsconfig/gsproduction.html) article by Geo-Solutions and [Geoserver documentation](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/production/index.html).

**Challenge :** GeoServer's getting heavily used, and it is failing if requests are increased, so how to find its capacity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have fixed hardware, create a semi-randomized stress test and increase the number of clients until the server either starts mis-behaving or the throughput does not go up any longer.

This documentation shows a possible way to do it:
https://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/educational/en/enterprise/index.html